# Oracle deadlock output when caused by foreign keys

Tags: oracle, database-deadlocks

We have a multi-threaded batch job ending up in deadlock.  I am getting conflicting answers from our dba's as to what actually causes the deadlock.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00060: deadlock detected while waiting for resource
```

The error output references the sql for inserting into table A.  Every row going into table A should be unique.  Table A has foreign keys on two other tables, both of which are indexed and primary keys made up of two columns.  Many rows in Table A can point to the same FK in the parent tables. Our code handles FK errors by trying to insert into parent tables and then trying into Table A again.

The sql in the trace log refers to the Table A insert sql (does not show param binding values). Does this mean definitively that there are two identical sql statements trying to be inserted into Table A in which case our prior logic is not thread-safe somewhere?  Or could it really be that there are two inserts both referencing an unsatisfied FK? And the deadlock occurs from our error handling in trying to insert into the parent table.  If so, would the sql in the trace not then reference the parent table sql?

Or perversely, does the original insert attempt put a lock on the row and then after handling the error, does the second attempt of the insert cause the deadlock?  Any further debugging assistance?

Comment: Thanks futevolei.  You mentioned that every row going into table A should be unique.  Maybe it is implied, but can you confirm that in the multi-threaded java piece,  there are no duplicate records that could be farmed out to different executors?  One avenue to a deadlock in this model could be if the same 2+ `table-A` records were assigned to two different sessions and executed in a different order.  Also, a look at the java code, the tables, their constraints, their indexes would be useful if available.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much info to work with, but my guess would be that two threads are trying to insert the same rows into one of the 'two other tables' at the same time. Idea on debugging below

- Use a trigger on table A and on the other two tables ( 3 triggers in total) that write the inserted data to logging tables in an autonomous transaction that commits. This way you can see the uncommitted inserts that were rolled back due to the deadlock (the rows that exists in the logging tables but not in the actual tables are the ones that were rolled back).

HTH, KR

Comment: The db's are managed by another team so unfortunately I can't modify the tables.  However, I guess the crux of what I am asking is this: is it possible for the deadlock error to show the sql statement for the destination table when its really being caused by one of the FK tables?  Or is the sql, always without fail, the actual table its trying to insert into?

Comment: Hi. I can't directly answer your question as I do not know. But you always need two sessions ( not one) for a lock and it takes some time before Oracle realizes that it is a deadlock. So, if you can reproduce the problem you can use v$lock and v$session when the lock is already there but it's not flagged as deadlock yet to see who locks whom. HTH KR